# How to implement Win32 macro MAKEINTRESOURCE

Tags: java, winapi, jna

Hi can you help with implementation macro MAKEINTRESOURCEW. When I view to the header file I found this:

```
#define MAKEINTRESOURCEW(i) ((LPWSTR)((ULONG_PTR)((WORD)(i))))
```

I need this functionality for my program where I am implementing the IContextMenu functionality to view explorer context menu. In all my items which I have tested I can get command string with function GetCommandString. But in one item I don't get the command string. And the item is Edit with Notepad++. So I have found in documentation that in the lpverb in structure [CMINVOKECOMMANDINFOEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ns-shobjidl_core-cminvokecommandinfoex) use the id of the item with macro MAKEINTRESOURCE.

But now I don't know how to invoke the command with id of this item and replace this macro.

This is my java code:

```
Memory numberVerb = new Memory(Native.POINTER_SIZE);
numberVerb.setLong(0, 109);

CMINVOKECOMMANDINFOEX cmInvokeCommandEx = new CMINVOKECOMMANDINFOEX();          
cmInvokeCommandEx.cbSize = cmInvokeCommandEx.size();                            
cmInvokeCommandEx.fMask = 0x00004000;                                           
cmInvokeCommandEx.hwnd = null;                                                                         
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpVerbW = new WTypes.LPWSTR(numberVerb);                      
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpVerb = new WTypes.LPSTR(verb);                              
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpParameters = null;                                          
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpParametersW = null;                                         
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpDirectory = new WTypes.LPSTR(parentDir.getAbsolutePath());  
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpDirectoryW = new WTypes.LPWSTR(parentDir.getAbsolutePath());
cmInvokeCommandEx.nShow = 5;                                                    
cmInvokeCommandEx.dwHotKey = 0;                                                 
cmInvokeCommandEx.hIcon = Pointer.NULL;                                         
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpTitle = null;                                               
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpTitleW = null;                                              
cmInvokeCommandEx.ptInvoke = point;                                             
cmInvokeCommandEx.write();                                                      
                                                                            
hResult = contextMenu2.InvokeCommand(cmInvokeCommandEx.getPointer());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution of this problem. I am upgrading my code for this:

```
result = User32Ex.INSTANCE.GetMenuItemInfoW(hMenu.getPointer(), 4, true, menuiteminfow.getPointer());
if (!result.booleanValue()) {
   int errorCode = Native.getLastError();
   System.out.println("Error Code: " + errorCode);
   return false;
}

CMINVOKECOMMANDINFOEX cmInvokeCommandEx = new CMINVOKECOMMANDINFOEX();          
cmInvokeCommandEx.cbSize = cmInvokeCommandEx.size();                            
cmInvokeCommandEx.fMask = 0x00004000;                                           
cmInvokeCommandEx.hwnd = null;                                                                         
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpVerbW = new WTypes.LPWSTR(new Pointer(menuiteminfow.wId - 1));                      
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpVerb = new WTypes.LPSTR(new Pointer(menuiteminfow.wId - 1));                              
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpParameters = null;                                          
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpParametersW = null;                                         
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpDirectory = new WTypes.LPSTR(parentDir.getAbsolutePath());  
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpDirectoryW = new WTypes.LPWSTR(parentDir.getAbsolutePath());
cmInvokeCommandEx.nShow = 5;                                                    
cmInvokeCommandEx.dwHotKey = 0;                                                 
cmInvokeCommandEx.hIcon = Pointer.NULL;                                         
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpTitle = null;                                               
cmInvokeCommandEx.lpTitleW = null;                                              
cmInvokeCommandEx.ptInvoke = point;                                             
cmInvokeCommandEx.write();                                                      
                                                                        
hResult = contextMenu2.InvokeCommand(cmInvokeCommandEx.getPointer());
```

**The key change is that when you want invoke command threw the id and not the command you must define the wId to the lpVerb variable and not to the lpVerbW or both. Because the lpVerbW is for the unicode string command only.**

Answer (score 2):

> So I have found in documentation that in the `lpverb` in structure `CMINVOKECOMMANDINFOEX` use the id of the item with macro `MAKEINTRESOURCE`

Read the [`CMINVOKECOMMANDINFOEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ns-shobjidl_core-cminvokecommandinfoex) documentation again more carefully, you DO NOT provide it with an *ID*, but with an *OFFSET* instead:

> `lpVerb`
>
> Type: `LPCSTR`
>
> The address of a null-terminated string that specifies the language-independent name of the command to carry out. This member is typically a string when a command is being activated by an application. The system provides predefined constant values for the following command strings.
>
> ```
> Constant          Command string
> CMDSTR_RUNAS      "RunAs"
> CMDSTR_PRINT      "Print"
> CMDSTR_PREVIEW    "Preview"
> CMDSTR_OPEN       "Open"
> ```
>
> This is not a fixed set; new canonical verbs can be invented by context menu handlers and applications can invoke them.
>
> If a canonical verb exists and a menu handler does not implement the canonical verb, it must return a failure code to enable the next handler to be able to handle this verb. Failing to do this will break functionality in the system including ShellExecute.
>
> **Alternatively, rather than a pointer, this parameter can be `MAKEINTRESOURCE(offset)` where `offset` is the menu-identifier offset of the command to carry out.** Implementations can use the `IS_INTRESOURCE` macro to detect that this alternative is being employed. **The Shell uses this alternative when the user chooses a menu command.**

So, when using `MAKEINTRESOURCE()` with `CMINVOKECOMMANDINFOEX::lpVerb`, you are not supposed to provide the actual ID of the menu item you want to invoke (especially since you don't know which ID was assigned to which menu item by `IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu()`).  You are supposed to provide the *offset* of the menu item instead (where the *value* of the offset is type-casted as-is into a character pointer - that is all `MAKEINTRESOURCE()` does).

You have some control over those offsets yourself, when you call `IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu()` to setup the menu items.  This is stated in the [`IContextMenu::InvokeCommand()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-icontextmenu-invokecommand) documentation:

> The `IContextMenu` interface is exported by several Shell extension handlers and namespace extensions. It is used to add commands to shortcut menus. When the user selects one of the commands that the handler or namespace extension added to a shortcut menu, the Shell calls that command's `InvokeCommand` method. **The command can be specified by its menu identifier offset, defined when `IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu` was called, or by its associated verb.** An application can invoke this method directly by obtaining a pointer to an object's `IContextMenu` interface. An application can also invoke this method indirectly by calling `ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteEx` and specifying a verb that is supported by the namespace extension or handler.

So, when you call each handler's `QueryContextMenu()` method, you have to specify the offset within your own `HMENU` where the handler can insert its menu items, and the minimum and maximum range of IDs that the handler can assign to those menu items. That way, when you are later notified via `WM_COMMAND` which menu item ID was selected, you can figure out which handler it belongs to by comparing the reported ID to the ranges you specified, and when you find a match then subtract that handler's minimum ID from the reported ID and pass the resulting offset to that handler's `InvokeCommand()` method.  Or, you can use the handler's `GetCommandString()` method to get the verb string of the menu item at that offset and then pass that verb string to `InvokeCommand()`.

And just FYI, `"Edit with Notepad++"` is the help string reported by Notepad++'s `IContextMenu::GetCommandString()` implementation for that menu item, so the fact that Windows Explorer can display that text means Notepad++'s handler works just fine.  If you are not able to retrieve that same text when calling `GetCommandString()` yourself, then you are not using `GetCommandString()` properly.  You should be able to display and execute *every* menu item that is created by every handler's `QueryContextMenu()`, just like the standard Windows Explorer Shell can.